# 500 - Internal Server Error, Windows Azure Cloud Service

Tags: c#, web-services, azure, deployment, azure-storage

I have just switched from WCF Service to Windows Azure Cloud Service.
I have copied over my codes from my WCF service into the Cloud service. 
When i run the website i get

> 500 - Internal Server Error.
>   There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Here is my code for my Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
 <add name="PCSDB" connectionString="Data Source=vlnucbukr8.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=PCSDB;User ID=ProjectPublicLogin;Password=****" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <system.diagnostics>
   <trace>
     <listeners>
      <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"name="AzureDiagnostics">
        <filter type="" />
       </add>
    </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
 <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
 <system.serviceModel>
   <services>
     <service name ="WCFServiceWebRole1.AllocationService">
      <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="AllocationBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="WCFServiceWebRole1.IAllocationService">
       </endpoint>
      <host>
       <baseAddresses>
         <add baseAddress="http://localhost/allocationservice"/>
        </baseAddresses>
     </host>
    </service>
  </services>
   <behaviors>
     <serviceBehaviors>
       <behavior>
         <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
       </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AllocationBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
   </endpointBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
 </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
   <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <httpErrors>
     <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100" />
      <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/errors.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution..

```
  <configSections>  </configSections>
```

have to be the first child of the

```
  <configuration>
```

tag

Answer (score 0):

Rather than Copying the whole code from service to cloud proejct, Add a Cloud project in Solution and then right click roles and add existing role from solution.